# Auto insert text (or code) on article

Tags: overrides, joomla-3.6

I try to find a way to auto insert code or text to every article on submission. I find this article on joomla https://docs.joomla.org/Add_text_to_an_article_using_template_overrides ,that uses template overrides to make this happen.Using this code:

```
var text = <?php 
    $addToText = '<p>Joomla! automatically added this text.</p>'; 
    if (strpos($this->article->text, $addToText) == 0) {
           $this->article->text .= $addToText;
    }
   echo $this->editor->getContent( 'text' ); ?>
```

on form.php file

,but this article is very old, i guess from joomla 1.5...

Comment: Are you trying to display a specific text after every article?

Comment: I want to try to insert <hr id="system-readmore" /> after a specific number of characters inside my articles.

Comment: Have you tried this : https://docs.joomla.org/Splitting_an_Article_into_an_introduction_with_a_link_to_read_more

Comment: This is the manual way to insert readmore in articles. I need the automatic way using template override.

Answer (score 1):

For what you describe, you will need to look into writing a plugin rather than using template overrides. You should be able to grab the content before it saves to the database and add any extra code at that point.

I think `onContentBeforeSave` would be the appropriate event to use in your case.

Template overrides still work in Joomla 3, but they just render the content differently rather than actually save it.  Depending what you want to do, this may also work.  A more up-to-date article on that is here:  https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core